# invalid conversion from 'Complex*' to 'Test*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, class

I have this code that I'd like to test with but for some reason I get the error above:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
    private:
       int real;
       int imag;
    public:
       Complex(): real(0), imag(0) { }
       void Read()
        {
           cout<<"Enter real and imaginary number respectively:"<<endl;
           cin>>real>>imag;
        }
        Complex* Add(Complex* comp2)
        {
            Complex* temp;
            temp->real=real+comp2->real;
/* Here, real represents the real data of object c1 because this function is called using code c1.Add(c2) */
            temp->imag=imag+comp2->imag;
/* Here, imag represents the imag data of object c1 because this function is called using code c1.Add(c2) */
            return temp;
        }
        void Display()
        {
            cout<<"Sum="<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i";
        }
};

class Test: public Complex
{
public:

    Test() {};
    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "\nObject destroyed\n";   
    };
};


int main()
{
    //Complex c1,c2;
    Complex* c1 = new Complex();
    Complex* c2 = new Complex();
    //Test c3;
    Test* c3  = new Test();
    c1->Read();
    c2->Read();
    //c3.Read();
    c3=c1->Add(c2);
    c3->Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone help me with the error? Where does it comes from?

Note: I'm doing some test about a derived class being able to work with methods and objects from a base class.
I'd like to create c3 a Test-type object that can use use 2 Complex-type objects that are added and then displayed via the display method from the base class (hope it makes sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line `c3 = c1->Add(c2);` you're trying to assign a `Complex*` (the base class) to `c3` (`Test*` - the derived class), which is illegal. You cannot assign a base class to a derived class, but the other way around it is legal.

Comment: so in order to achieve my goal I should have declared c2 and c1 to be type Test and c3 type Complex to call Add() using c1 and c2 ?